# NHibernate Linq queries not returning data saved in the same transaction

Tags: linq, wcf, nhibernate, transactions

I have a situation where I am using NHibernate in a WCF service and using a TransactionScope for the transaction management. NHibernate enlists in the ambient transaction fine, but, any changes I make and save inside the transaction, are not visible to any queries I make while still in that transaction.
So if I add an entity and session.save() it, then further on in the code, there is a linq query against that entities table, the entity I just added is not returned.

Strangely this seems to work fine if I use explicit NHibernate transactions in my tests.

Anyone have any ideas as to why and what I can do about it?

Many thanks

Andrew

Comment: Which version of NHibernate and Linq are you using?  The trunk?  Can you show a failing unit test?

Comment: I've posted an answer that, actually, is a question, but the amount of related content turned impossible to just comment. Wait for your answer.